# What 'Login as a service' services are there?

Tags: api, service, authentication, cloud

I'm looking for a cloud solution to login management.  Basically, I want it to be just a login system.  No concept of levels or permissions or anything.

I imagine it being an API that I can sign up for and from my user's perspective, they are logging in to my site, but what it's doing is authenticating and storing the user up in this cloud service.

It could have basic user management, or I as admin could change the levels of authentication.
Also, this API would handle 'forgot password' and things like that as well.

So basically, it's an API.  I would still be responsible for the UI.

Does this exist?  I could really use it.  Writing login systems for each site/app idea is a lot of work, and I'd rather focus on my app.

Comment: look at OpenID Providers

Comment: If it's helpful, I compared (5/18/2015):

 - Auth0
 - AuthRocket
 - UserApp
 - DailyCred

**Conclusion for me was Auth0**, because while all the features are very similar, it felt the most legitimate, as in it's not a start-up that might disappear in a few months. Login is a foundational requirement, so I need to believe as a customer that the Authentication as a Service will be up for as long as I will be.

Here's the full comparison story:
https://medium.com/@bsemaj/authentication-as-a-service-comparison-5-quick-lessons-for-b2b-businesses-e7587275824c

Answer (score 4):

I'm looking for exactly same thing.

There are two i found:

1.http://authrocket.com/ "Invitations are going out regularly"

2.http://loginify.com/  this one seems to be inactive since 2013

*EDIT*
3.Theres third one you might look at https://stormpath.com/, it has instant registration.

4. There's also a http://parse.com - it offers user management for web and mobile apps

Comment: Nice list, thanks. I wonder which services have datacenters in Europe. As it is asked by our clients. Can you put that as an attribute to the listed services? e.g. Stormpath looks like US based.

Answer (score 3):

[AuthRocket](http://authrocket.com/) can do pretty much everything you're asking for: signups, logins, forgotten passwords, management UI, etc.

In followup to the other answer, AuthRocket is now available to all--invitations no longer required.

Disclaimer: part of AuthRocket.

Answer (score 2):

The "Login as a Service" page is growing rapidly, so your options depend a lot on

1. what languages you're working in and
2. how your user needs may grow in the future.

Authrocket is a great option for Ruby.

[Stormpath](https://stormpath.com) is a user management API for [Node, Java and Python (and general REST)](https://docs.stormpath.com/home/) that does all the basic authentication and user workflows you're looking for. It also stores up to 10MB of schemaless JSON on each user, so you can have all your user data in there. And it does authorization, social login, API key authentication, and SSO as well. You can get the basic auth your looking for at the free tier, forever.

Disclaimer: I work at Stormpath.

Comment: From stormpath.com: "The Stormpath API shut down on August 17, 2017. Thank you to all the developers who have used Stormpath."